# typescript error of NaN

Tags: javascript, typescript

Sorry to ask similar question but I really can't seems to find a way out. I am stuck with this calculation. basically params a to g are the values of my input params from the HTML. I want to use it to calculate certain sum. I tried to console.log(+this.a) and it give me a number. But when I try to console.log(this.aa) it gives me NaN. May I know how I can work around it? Thank you.

From my typescript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-song',
  templateUrl: 'song.html',
})
export class SongPage {
  a:string;aa:number = +this.a * 2;
  b:string;bb:number = +this.b * 7;
  c:string;cc:number = +this.c * 6;
  d:string;dd:number = +this.d * 5;
  e:string;ee:number = +this.e * 4;
  f:string;ff:number = +this.f * 3;
  g:string;gg:number = +this.g * 2;
  sumA:number = (this.aa+this.bb+this.cc+this.dd+this.ee+this.ff);
  sumB:number = this.sumA%11;
  sumC:number = 11-this.sumB;

  char: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
  cal()
  {
    console.log(this.aa);
    if(this.sumC == 1)
    {
      this.char = 'A';
    }
    else if(this.sumC == 2)
    {
      this.char = 'B';
    }
    else if(this.sumC == 3)
    {
      this.char = 'C';
    }else if(this.sumC == 4)
    {
      this.char = 'D';
    }else if(this.sumC == 5)
    {
      this.char = 'E';
    }else if(this.sumC == 6)
    {
      this.char = 'F';
    }else if(this.sumC == 7)
    {
      this.char = 'G';
    }else if(this.sumC == 8)
    {
      this.char = 'H';
    }
    else if(this.sumC == 9)
    {
      this.char = 'I';
    }else if(this.sumC == 10)
    {
      this.char = 'Z';
    }else if(this.sumC == 11 || 0)
    {
      this.char = 'J';
    }else
    {
      this.char = 'NaN';
    }
  }

}
```

From my HTML

```
  <ion-input name="two" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="a"></ion-input>
  <ion-input name="three" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="b"></ion-input>
  <ion-input name="four" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="c"></ion-input>
  <ion-input name="five" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="d"></ion-input>
  <ion-input name="six" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="e"></ion-input>
  <ion-input name="seven" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="f"></ion-input>
  <ion-input name="eight" class="box" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="g"></ion-input>
  <button ion-button round block (click)="cal()">Validate</button>
  <h2>The character is: {{char}}</h2>
```

Comment: The problem is here: `aa:number = +this.a * 2;` This doesn't mean "ensure that `aa` is always the numeric value of `this.a`, times 2". It means: "make the starting value of `aa` equal to the current value of `this.a` (which is `undefined`, times 2" You need to recalculate your fields when the values of `a`, `b`, etc. change.

Comment: But when I console.log(this.a) and console.log(+this.a), it gives me the number that I input!

Comment: @DevJo Yes, `this.a` will have whatever value you give it. `this.aa` will not reflect changes made to `this.a` unless you update the value of `this.aa` somehow.

Comment: @JLRishe you are right! Hence I put in inside my cal() function instead and now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` to `g` are undefined so you have to get params values before calculation of `aa` or `bb` ... :

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.a = // <-- add value 
   this.a = // <-- add value 
   //...
   this.b = // <-- add value 

  this.aa = +this.a * 2;
  this.bb  = +this.b * 7;
  this.cc  = +this.c * 6;
  this.dd = +this.d * 5;
  this.ee  = +this.e * 4;
  this.ff = +this.f * 3;
  this.gg  = +this.g * 2;

 this.sumA  = (this.aa+this.bb+this.cc+this.dd+this.ee+this.ff);
 this.sumB  = this.sumA%11;
 this.sumC  = 11-this.sumB;

}
```